# Best Fit Memory Allocation

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement Best fit memory allocation. I have done the code, which i think should work but somehow it appears its getting stuck in the loop. I can't figure out why. The following is my code. I want to allocate jobs to the memory with the least memory waste.

```
public void bestFit(int job_size)
{
    string str1 = "";
    string str2 = "";
    string str3 = "";
    int memory_block = 99999;
    int subscript = 0;
    int initial_memory_waste = memory_block - job_array[0];
    int job_counter = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    int memory_waste = 0;
    while (counter <= memory_array.Length)
    {
        if (job_size > memory_array[counter - 1])
        {
            counter += 1;
        }
        else
            memory_waste = memory_array[counter - 1] - job_size;
        {
            if (initial_memory_waste > memory_waste)
            {
                subscript = counter;
                initial_memory_waste = memory_waste;
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    queued_jobs = counter;
    str3 = ("Job number: " + (queued_jobs).ToString() + " of size: " + job_size.ToString());
    if (job_counter < job_array.Length)
    {
        bf_waiting_queue.Add(str3);
    }
    else
    {
        str1 = ("Job number: " + (job_counter).ToString() + " of size: " + job_size.ToString() + " is allocated to Memory block: " + (subscript).ToString() + " of size: " + memory_array[subscript - 1]).ToString();
        memory_waste = memory_array[subscript - 1] - job_size;
        str2 = ("Memory waste is: " + memory_waste.ToString());
        bf_total_memory_waste += memory_waste;
        memory_array[counter - 1] = (memory_array[counter - 1] - job_size);
        bf_jobsInMemory.Add(str1 + "\t" + str2);
        job_counter += 1;
        counter = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `else
                memory_waste = memory_array[counter - 1] - job_size;
            {` ??

Comment: Broken indenting should be a strong hint.  Use { braces } consistently to avoid mistakes like this, even if the else clause only has one statement.  The compiler doesn't mind.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the braces issue others pointed out, your logic makes it possible for you to *never* increment 'counter', which is why you are stuck in the loop. The following reorganization is cleaner and guarantees you always increment 'counter'. Also, a couple of comments couldn't hurt.

```
while (counter <= memory_array.Length)
{
    // If block fits, consider it
    if (job_size <= memory_array[counter - 1])
    {
        memory_waste = memory_array[counter - 1] - job_size;

        // If this block is less wasteful, remember it
        if (initial_memory_waste > memory_waste)
        {
            subscript = counter;
            initial_memory_waste = memory_waste;
        }
    }

    // Next block
    counter += 1;
}
```